# Python / pandas - SettingWithCopyWarning using DatetimeIndex().day

Tags: python, pandas

I have code given the SettingWithCopy Warning and I can't figure out to recode it properly.

```
dataframe['day'] = pandas.DatetimeIndex(dataframe['date_time']).day
```

I am trying to make columns in the original dataframe holidng the day, year, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply by calling day:

```
df['day'] = df['date_time'].day
```

but I doubt this where the warning is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`Series.dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html), [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
df['day'] = df['date_time'].dt.day
df['year'] = df['date_time'].dt.year
```